# VB.NET InputBox not working Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

VB.NET InputBox not working Error prompt...
................................................................................................................................................................

```
Public Class Form1
        Dim user As String
        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            user = inputBox("Enter Your Name", "Input Box", "Bill Gates", 100, 100)
            Label1.Text = "Hello," & user
        End Sub
    End Class
```

> 'inputBox' is a namespace & can't be used as an expression

.
Error prompt : Can't start debugger because path\inputBox\exe' is missing

> I'm using VS 2010 ultimate

Comment: When you create a little project to test the InputBox() method then consider to not name this project "InputBox".  As-is you have to spell out the full name of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this..

```
   user = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Your Name", "Input 
            Box", "Bill Gates", 100, 100)
   Label1.Text = "Hello," & user
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Works fine now. The issue could be fixed by simply saving the project with any name other than inputbox. Else use this Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox()